Kubernetes on VScode
I have installed VS Code on Windows 11 Pro, and I have also installed the Kubernetes extension, but I can't get it to work. I can´t connect to any kubernete cluster.
I have been reading online and have tried adding the line
"vs-kubernetes.enable-snap-flag": true,
in the configuration.
I have installed Docker Desktop on my PC.
I have installed kubectl on my PC.
In my PC's command line, I can run "kubectl get nodes" without any problems.
But in VS Code I always get the error "kubectl command failed".
my "settings.json" code:
"vs-kubernetes": {
        "vs-kubernetes.enable-snap-flag": true,
        "vscode-kubernetes.helm-path-windows": "C:\\Users\\yvaldes\\.vs-kubernetes\\tools\\helm\\windows-amd64\\helm.exe",
        "vscode-kubernetes.kubectl-path-windows": "C:\\Users\\yvaldes\\.vs-kubernetes\\tools\\kubectl\\kubectl.exe",
        "vscode-kubernetes.minikube-path-windows": "C:\\Users\\yvaldes\\.vs-kubernetes\\tools\\minikube\\windows-amd64\\minikube.exe",
        "vs-kubernetes.knownKubeconfigs": [
            "c:\\Users\\yvaldes\\Downloads\\produccion (3).yaml",
            "c:\\Users\\yvaldes\\.kube\\config"
        ],
        "vs-kubernetes.kubeconfig": "c:\\Users\\yvaldes\\.kube\\config"
    },

any help ?

When I disconnect all folders from the explorer in VS Code, I can connect to the Kubernetes clusters. But if I add a folder to the explorer once more using SSH FS, I lose visibility again
